# Is there a way to list PostgreSQL servers?

Tags: postgresql, libpq, libpqxx

Currently I am writing client to PostgreSQL servers. I want to list the details (ip address and port number) of the servers that is running PostgreSQL servers in the local network. Is there some methods in libpq or libpqxx ?

Regards

Devara Gudda

Answer (score 6):

PostgreSQL has support for "bonjour", if your network supports it and PostgreSQL is built with it.

If you don't have that, then the answer is no. The closest you can get is to portscan the network on 5432 - but that still won't catch listeners on other ports.